# Error while i am trying to create a folder in sdcard

Tags: android, exception

Below is my code which i am using for download image from server and store in sd card in a folder , and it through again and again an exception

```
java.io.IOException: Not a directory
```

Kindly help me for that.

Comment: File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+type);
  if (!SDCardRoot.exists())
  {
            Boolean a= SDCardRoot.mkdir();
  }

Comment: please post relevant snippet of code

Answer (score 4):

add write permission to your app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then, try to create the directory

```
File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), type); 
if (!SDCardRoot.exists()) 
{ 
  SDCardRoot.mkdir(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi blackbelt
above code is not working
 SDCardRoot.mkdir() returns false.

Comment: did you add the write permission to your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
yup

Comment: do you have an sdcard and its state is MOUNTED ?

Comment: did you create an sdcard for the emulator?

Comment: who is throwing the exception, then?